# Python object response in development is different of production response

Tags: json, django, python-3.8

I already use a code that call an API request and from nothing this broken my code. I tried to check what happening, my object response does not have a valid json.

The instruction that I use is:

```
    def get_tickers(self, symbols):
        """Get tickers."""
        data = {"symbols": symbols}
        return self.session.get("%s/public/ticker" % self.url, params=data).json()
```

This work well until broken from nothing.

I use the same Dockerfile in Prod environment and Dev environment to prevent some differences that could be showing

In dev (Mac OS) my code still working and returns me this response:

```
[{'symbol': 'ETHBTC', 'ask': '0.034707', 'bid': '0.034705', 'last': '0.034699', 'low': '0.034477', 'high': '0.035257', 'open': '0.035083', 'volume': '89442.2126', 'volumeQuote': '3117.3903987376', 'timestamp': '2020-09-19T16:04:57.968Z'}, {'symbol': 'BTCUSD', 'ask': '11084.95', 'bid': '11084.14', 'last': '11086.54', 'low': '10813.93', 'high': '11177.98', 'open': '10890.52', 'volume': '18086.71200', 'volumeQuote': '198275586.9755433', 'timestamp': '2020-09-19T16:04:58.020Z'}]
```

In Prod (Ubuntu 18) this result is not a valid json, I know that single quotes is not a valid json, but, my questions is: Why in dev this working and prod not? I using python 3.8. Same dockerfile, same versions, same code, same base, same endpoint.

On prod, if I get response with .content, because .json() does not working, I get this:

```
{{"symbol":"BTCUSD","ask":"11060.46","bid":"11060.10","last":"11061.35","low":"10813.93","high":"11177.98","open":"10880.48","volume":"18030.10398","volumeQuote":"197564156.9442369","timestamp":"2020-09-19T15:31:15.785Z"},{"symbol":"ETHUSD","ask":"383.999","bid":"383.968","last":"383.993","low":"374.765","high":"388.200","open":"380.909","volume":"299403.4718","volumeQuote":"114216954.4166669","timestamp":"2020-09-19T15:31:15.750Z"},{"symbol":"ETHBTC","ask":"0.034704","bid":"0.034700","last":"0.034702","low":"0.034477","high":"0.035257","open":"0.034989","volume":"92961.2267","volumeQuote":"3240.5534764060","timestamp":"2020-09-19T15:31:15.784Z"}}
```

Anyone already get this error?

Does the environment handle the response before going to .json()?

Comment: What kind of response do you get on production? Could you post the example?

Comment: @DmitryBelaventsev, I put response at the body of question. The same response I guess, because, .json() does not working. So, I get via .content 
self.session.get("%s/public/ticker" % self.url, params=data).content

Comment: Could you also post the code, which set the value on session object?

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. On dev environment, response give me a string that starts with '['

```
[{'symbol': 'ETHBTC', ...
```

On prod, response give me a string that starts with '{':

```
{{'symbol': 'ETHBTC', ...
```

This is strange, because, I used same base, same environment, same version, same endpoint, same vars ... so, I found the error, but not the solution.

I put this durex in my code due to put that to work

```
data = {"symbols": symbols}
rest = self.session.get("%s/public/ticker" % self.url, params=data).text
string = rest[1:]   # remove first character
string = string[:-1] # remove last
return  json.loads('['+string+']') # put the code between brackets
```

One thing is certain, the response is treated in the application layer in different ways depending on the environment or the versions, not entirely at the source

If anyone has a less ugly solution, please feel free to post to us.

Comment: It could be a one-liner: `return json.loads(f'[{rest[1:-1]}]')`. But give me some time I think I know why you have different result.

Comment: The response is probably being interpreted differently depending on the environment or build version. I didn't quite understand this error.

Comment: Can you shoe me the code, which writes to the session?

Comment: This API is a public endpoint, so you can use this: https://api.hitbtc.com/api/2/public/ticker/?symbols=EURSUSD,TRXEOS,LTCEURS,NEOEOS. The complete code is the first function in this post. ... def get_tickers( ...

Comment: I'm interested in the code, which writes that value to the session. During the read operation you get different values on local/prod - so we should check how you write data first to get answers.

Comment: Right ... this is the way local/prod. Same data, same database, same endpoint.
data = {"symbols": "ETHBTC,BTCUSD,ETHUSD"}
return self.session.get("https://api.hitbtc.com/api/2/public/ticker/", params=data).json()

Comment: Ah, so `self.session` is kind of thing from `requests` library, right? I thought you store Django Session there.

Comment: So yea, it also work for me on local and on couple of aws servers. I mean I get correct response. Do you still have problem on prod or it's happening randomly? If randomly, then we can add try/except to catch the error and conditions when this errors happens.

Comment: And could you also try curl from your production server? To see if curl get correct data.

Comment: and are you sure that self.url is the same on both envs?

Comment: Actually I always say that there's no magic in tech. There's always a reason.